# io:format control sequence strings with arguments

Tags: erlang

> The format of a control sequence is ~F.P.PadModC. If F, P, or Pad is *, the next argument in Data is used as the numeric value of F or P.

Where can I find some example of io:format with control sequence with parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to find with a google search at least. Erlang docs describes it all but its hard to find code examples. '' around the output are used for representing spaces.

```
>io:format("'~*s'", [10, "test"]). % right align space padded
>'      test'
>io:format("'~*s'", [-10, "test"]). % left align space padded
>'test      '
>io:format("'~*B'", [10, 99]). % space padded right aligned integer
>'        99'
>io:format("'~*B'~n", [-10, 88]). % space padded left aligned integer
>'88        '
>io:format("'~*.*f'~n", [-10,5,77.1234]). % left aligned space padded float with precision
>'77.12340  '
```

Hope this helps someone like me. Wish to see more hard to find example added to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Some more examples.

1. c

   - `>io:format("~*.c",[3,$c]).`

     `>cccok`
   - `> io:format("~*.*c",[10,2,$c]). % F=10 , P = 2`

     `>        ccok`
   - `> io:format("~*.*.-c",[10,2,$c]). % F=10 , P=2 and Pad= -(hyphen)`

     `>--------ccok`
2. e

   - `> io:format("~*.*./e",[10,2,223.45]). % F= 10 , P =2 and Pad= /(forward slash)`

     `>////2.2e+2ok % unlike f  precision in case of e is total number of digits`